# PLSQL- UPDATE USING CURSOR CAUSING RECURSIVE LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, recursive-query

```
DECLARE
CURSOR emp_cur
IS
    SELECT ename,empno,dname,sal
    FROM emp3
    WHERE dname='SALES';
BEGIN 
    FOR emp_rec IN emp_cur
    LOOP
        IF emp_rec.dname='SALES' THEN
            UPDATE emp3
            SET sal = sal + sal*0.10
            WHERE empno = emp_rec.empno;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

> ***Cause**: An attempt was made to go more than the specified number
> of recursive SQL levels.
>
> ***Action**: Remove the recursive SQL, possibly a recursive trigger.

I am getting this error while trying to update using cursor. What changes should I do?

Comment: Post a reproducible test case.  My wager is that you have some piece of code that you haven't included here that is actually causing the problem.  Most likely, as the action suggests, there is a trigger on `emp3` that fires when the `update` is run that is actually the source of the problem.

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example: table definitions, sample data for these tables and how do you call this code. Currently it is not reproducible: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5964cd905c0dbf7e191b4717892bd00e)

Answer (score 0):

The code u wrote doesnt make any sense to me, 1st why would u use pls sql cursor instead of simple update..set..where sql command, 2nd why loop 'for loop'
through cursor when u can simply write: for i in (select statement), 3rd this line:    where empno = emp_rec.empno; is nonsensical, u are looping through cursor u are not joining tables.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.